# ADOdb gives "Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference"

Tags: php, adodb-php

I've using ADOdb `Execute` function:

```
$query = "select * from users where user_id = ? and PWD = ?";
$execute = $conn->Execute($query,array($username, $password));
```

Which gives the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference
```

I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the `Execute` method is declared as `public function Execute($query, &$params)` meaning the second method is expected to be passed by reference. Thus you have to pass a variable. Try this:

```
$query = "select * from users where user_id = ? and PWD = ?";
$params = array($username, $password);
$execute = $conn->Execute($query, $params);
```

Comment: This is probably it - although the [adodb documentation](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) shows  examples with arrays directly as parameters. Weird.

Comment: @Pekka웃, It seems like a lousy library.